# How to get my own Facebook user timeline using Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to get all the posts and updates that are normally displayed in FB official application for MY account (this includes updates from my friends and liked pages).

I wasn't able to find any details how to get that, the only thing I've managed to get is my own posts.

Anyone got any experience with that using current Graph API verion (3.3)?

All the alternate FB clients (ex. [Friendly](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.friendly&hl=en)) must be doing this somehow.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get ANY data of users who did not authorized your App. Which means, there is no way to get posts of friends. You can only get your own friends, with the `user_posts` permission and the `/me/posts` endpoint. If some Apps access friend data without their authorization, they are most likely doing something that is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found in their API docs:

There are two scopes:

The [user feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.3/user/feed) requires the user's permission

The [public feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed/) has fewer capabilities but doesn't require perms